# Getting strange http time out error in threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm using the ARIN rest whois service to look up the organizations for a list of IP addresses.  Since the list is very long (the one below is just a very small subset), I opted to do this with threads for faster performance.

```
public class SimpleThreadPool {

    public final static String[] ips = { 
        "192.150.16.64","192.243.232.36","208.77.139.8","63.140.35.160",
        "63.140.35.161","63.140.35.162","63.140.59.142","63.140.61.200",
        "66.235.132.238","66.235.137.133","66.235.138.18","66.235.138.192",
        "66.235.138.195","66.235.139.152","66.235.139.172","66.235.139.204",
        "66.235.139.205","66.235.139.206","66.235.139.227","66.235.141.144",
        "66.235.141.145","66.235.141.146","66.235.141.16","66.235.142.20",
        "66.235.142.24","66.235.141.145","184.106.60.35","207.171.162.26",
        "207.171.162.75","207.171.162.95","207.171.185.201","207.171.187.117",
        "207.171.187.118","207.171.189.80","207.171.189.81","216.137.37.108",
        "216.137.37.122","216.137.37.128","216.137.37.138","216.137.37.140",
        "216.137.37.178","216.137.37.183","216.137.37.198","216.137.37.225",
        "216.137.37.235","216.137.37.37","216.137.37.52","216.137.37.57",
        "216.137.37.6","216.137.37.84" 
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        for (int i = 0; i < ips.length; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread(ips[i]);
            executor.execute(worker);
        }

        executor.shutdown();

        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {}

        System.out.println("All threads finished.");
    }
}
```

And here is WorkerThread:

```
public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    private String workingIP;

    public WorkerThread(String workingIP) {
        this.workingIP = workingIP;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://whois.arin.net/rest/ip/" + workingIP);

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)(url.openConnection());
            con.connect();
            inputStream = con.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

            String line = null;
            while( (line=br.readLine()) != null )
            {
                if (line.contains("<td>Organization</td><td>")) {
                    String companyName = line.replace("<td>Organization</td><td>", "").trim();
                    System.out.println(workingIP + " maps to: " + companyName);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

On my work machine (w/ an i5-2400, 4GB RAM, 32bit Win7), this code works fine all the way down to around the 45th+ IP address in the array.  Then I get `java.net.ConnectException` errors thrown for the remaining lookups:

```
...
216.137.37.57 maps to: Amazon.com, Inc.
216.137.37.6 maps to: Amazon.com, Inc.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
       at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
```

If I change the executor's thread pool size to 1, then everything works and no errors are thrown, but obviously the lookups take a lot longer.

The really strange thing is that if I run this same code on my 2011 Core i7 Mac, no errors whatsoever are thrown.  Granted, the two are on different networks (my work machine uses my work's network, while my Mac is wirelessly tethered to a smartphone).

Any idea what's going on here, and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write sane error-handling code. It really is that simple. What do you want to do if the connection times out? If you make a lot of connections at once on a slow network, some of them may time out.

Comment: I agree that the catch statement above is not ideal.  It's really just there to illustrate the nature of the problem (the error handling will be more robust in the finished app).  The problem is not a slow network though (my work connection is @ 25+ Mb/s down).  I could catch these exceptions and maybe attempt to retry the request, but then I might as well stick with the single-threaded solution, where this error is never thrown, since that'll likely be faster for a much longer list.

Comment: @Brutalisk The multi-threaded solution will be much faster for a longer list, so long as you pace yourself sanely and back off if you start getting connection errors.